# Routing legacy URLs with query parameters in .NET core razor pages

Tags: .net-core, url-routing, razor-pages

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 5.0 web app. It must have support for users that has legacy urls, eg.
contoso.com/privacy.aspx?EmpNo=12&Date=2021-01-07

The URL should be routed to something like
contoso.com/privacy/12/2021-01-07

At the moment I've got this in my privacy.cshtml

```
@page "{id:int?}/{date:datetime?}"
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"] @RouteData.Values["id"] @RouteData.Values["date"]</h1>
```

And in my Startup.cs I've gotten this to work

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();

            endpoints.MapGet("privacy.aspx", async context =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/privacy"));
            });
        });
    }
```

This only redirects privacy.aspx to /privacy.
When I try to add query parameters, it fails with: RoutePatternException: The literal section 'privacy.aspx?EmpNo=' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/privacy", "privacy.aspx?EmpNo={id}&Date={date}");
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it was quite simple after some trial and error:

```
endpoints.MapGet("privacy.aspx", async context =>
            {
                var query = context.Request.QueryString;
                await Task.Run(() => context.Response.Redirect("/privacy" + query.Value));
            });
```

Then you can get the values in the get method:

```
 public void OnGet([FromQuery(Name = "EmpNo")] string empNo, [FromQuery(Name = "Date")] DateTime date)
    {
        
    }
```